# Core Data + NSFetchedResultsController in SWIFT

Tags: core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I will try to make it as simple as possible i am fetching from core data using NSFetchedResultsController my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let newEntry : Entry = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Entry
    cell.textLabel.text = newEntry.title
    return cell
}
```

My app crashes

When I replace the line below

```
let newEntry : Entry = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Entry
```

With this line the app works records populate tableview no errors no problems

```
let newEntry : AnyObject! = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

The question is WHY is not AnyObject is an Entry NSManagedObject

Thank You

Comment: Advice: two questions should be written as two separate questions in SO.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with NSFetchedResultsController, but Objective-C needs to recognize your NSManagedObject subclass. Just add the @objc(Entry) in your NSManagedObject subclass:

```
@objc(Entry)
class Entry: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I don't think @ngeran was looking to use the class in Objective-C, and adding `@objc(Entry)` does not fix the problem in Swift for me. It has something to do with the NSManagedObject Swift namespacing, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. Now I have successfully rectified it as per the latest iOS version. Hope my code helps.

```
if let newEntry = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Entry{
   cell.textLabel?.text = newEntry.title 
}
return cell
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out!

```
if let access:Entry = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Entry {
    cell.textLabel?.text = access.valueForKey("title") as? String
}
```

And then `return` to `cell`