# swift core data retrieve entity (uiimage)

Tags: swift, core-data, uiimageview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am relatively new to swift and xcode. I am trying to implement a tableView with entities (UserModel) from CoreData. The TableView Cell has one UIImageView and one UILabel. I am able to implement the UILabel with the usermodel.name but somehow I can not implement the UIImageView with the usermodel.image. Even more strange is that I can not create a temporary user and assign him the values from the NSFetchRequest.

I first tried to manage the fetchrequest by myself:

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkList: UITableView!
var friendsArray: [AnyObject] = []
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserModel")

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("checkCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    friendsArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    let cellName: String? = friendsArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.name.text = cellName
    return cell
}
```

This code displays the 6 labels of the 6 first cells correctly implemented with the different names of the entities stored in CoreData. Now when I try to retrieve the image as well:

```
        let userImage:UIImage = UIImage(data:friendsArray[indexPath.row].avatar)
    cell.avatar.image = userImage
```

Xcode says 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'avatar'. Therefore I try to first cast the user instance into a temporary user as this:

```
        let user:UserModel? = friendsArray[indexPath.row] as UserModel
```

But this causes the code to crash. I tried to create an external function that would take the user's name and return the user's avatar directly as a UIImage. But I got the same crash.

I finally tried with an NSFetchedResultsController correctly implemented but it still crashes. 
There is nothing in the console but xcode displays a long list of threads. Here is the first one.

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional: 
0x26f8a80:  pushl  %ebp
0x26f8a81:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x26f8a83:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
0x26f8a86:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x26f8a88:  je     0x26f8a9b                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 27
0x26f8a8a:  movl   0xc(%ebp), %ecx
0x26f8a8d:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x26f8a8f:  nop    
0x26f8a90:  cmpl   %ecx, %edx
0x26f8a92:  je     0x26f8ab8                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 56
0x26f8a94:  movl   0x4(%edx), %edx
0x26f8a97:  testl  %edx, %edx
0x26f8a99:  jne    0x26f8a90                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 16
0x26f8a9b:  calll  0x26f8aa0                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 32
0x26f8aa0:  popl   %eax
0x26f8aa1:  leal   0x382a2(%eax), %ecx
0x26f8aa7:  movl   0x775ac(%eax), %eax
0x26f8aad:  movl   %ecx, 0x8(%eax)
0x26f8ab0:  movl   $0x0, 0xc(%eax)
0x26f8ab7:  int3   
0x26f8ab8:  popl   %ebp              Thread1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)
0x26f8ab9:  retl   
0x26f8aba:  nopw   (%eax,%eax)
```

I really don't know what to do. If anyone has an idea I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the version with the NSFetchedResultsController

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CheckFlowViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var checkList: UITableView!
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
var fetchedResultController:NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchedResultController = getFetchedResultController()
    fetchedResultController.delegate = self
    fetchedResultController.performFetch(nil)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:CheckTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("checkCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CheckTableViewCell
    let user:UserModel = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UserModel
    //I don't even try to implement the cell.name.text as it already crashes with this line above.
}

func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: theFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultController
}

func theFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserModel")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}

//NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    println("hi")
}

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your approach with `NSFetchedResultsController` is correct (doing fetch in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was terribly inefficient). But can you please show the code of your implementation using `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Hi @MichałCiuba thank you for your attention.
I have updated the question with the NSFetchedResultsController implementation. I hope it will help

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25616573/2128900

Comment: You just saved my computer from basejumping. Thank you so much. I have been stuck on this for two days. And yes, next time I will look deeper in other posts before asking. 
You made my day.

Comment: You're welcome, but the credits go to the author of the answer I linked. You can upvote it if you find it helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data + NSFetchedResultsController in SWIFT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783904/core-data-nsfetchedresultscontroller-in-swift)